# Calculating the derivation of $F(t):=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-tx}}{x}\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis

> > As the title says, i have to calculate $F'(t)$ for
> >     $$
> > F(t):=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-tx}}{x}\, dx.
> > $$

What I already have is
$$
F'(t)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-e^{-tx-hx}-e^{-tx}}{hx}\, dx.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have
$$\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-tx}}{x}= \sim_{x\to0}t-1$$
so the function $x\mapsto \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-tx}}{x}$ has a finite limit at $0$ and then it's integrable on the interval $(0,1]$, moreover

$$\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-tx}}{x}=_{x\to\infty}o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
so the function $x\mapsto \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-tx}}{x}$ is integrable on the interval $[1,+\infty)$ and then the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{|e^{-x}-e^{-tx}|}{x}dx$$
exists.

The function

$$f\colon t\mapsto \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-tx}}{x},\quad t>0$$
is differentiable and we have
$$|f'(t)|=e^{-tx}\leq e^{-ax}\quad\forall t\geq a>0$$
and since the function $x\mapsto e^{-ax}$ is integrable on $[0,+\infty)$ then by the Leibniz theorem $F$ is differentiable and
$$F'(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}dx=\frac{1}{t}$$

**Added** Clearly $F(1)=0$ so we conclude 
$$F(t)=\log t.$$

Comment: didn't you forget to show that $f(x,\cdot)$ is integrable for any x? On which version of the leiniz theorem are you working?

Comment: And how could one show that?

Comment: Thank you! Very kind of you.

Comment: Oh, i do not know that notation... what means $=\~x\to 0$? And what $=x\to\infty o(1/x^2)$?

Comment: Yes, you used it and then $x\to 0$?

Comment: I now see that the function is t-1 when $x\to 0$. But why is it integrable on $(0,1]$ then?

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand. But maybe i ask too much ;(

Comment: Sorry. I do not see yet that $\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-tx}}{x}=o(1/x^2), x\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes, but I do not see that this is right.^^ resp. I do not know how to see that.

Comment: So you made the following: It is to show that $\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-tx}}{x}$ is integrable over $[0,\infty]$. You splitted the integral in an integral over $[0,1]$ and one over $[1,\infty]$. The function is integrable ober [0,1] because it has an continious extension on this intervall. Additionally $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\lvert e^{-x}-e^{-tx}\rvert}{x}\, dx\leq\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lvert x^2\rvert}\, dx=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\, dx=1<\infty$. So all together its integrable ober $[0,\infty]$. So you used two different possibilites to show that it is differentiable (continity and abs)?

Comment: But how can one say that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\lvert e^{-x}-e^{-tx}\rvert}{x}\, dx\leq\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\, dx$ when $\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-tx}}{x}\leq \frac{1}{x^2}$ only for big x?

Comment: Ah, you mean: Split $[0,\infty]$ in $[0,x_0]$ and $[x_0,\infty]$, then using the extension-argumentation for $[0,x_0]$ and the other argumenation for $[x_0,\infty]$? (This was my last question, I promise!!)

Comment: i am student, 8 th semester, but nevertheless i still have my problems

Comment: Dankeschön! The problem is, that many themes were not teached in analysis... f.e. the landau symbols.